# What is the correct way to format long lines of code in python?

Tags: python

I've got some lines of code that return and assign multiple values from a function, like below. This of course makes it one very long line. What's the correct way to style/format a line of code like this? I've included a couple of possibilities that I've come up with.

```
some_variable_1, \
    some_variable_2, \ 
    some_variable_3, \
    some_variable_4, \
    some_variable_5 = sort_of_long_function_name(parameter_1, parameter_2,
    parameter_3, parameter_4)

some_variable_1, some_variable_2, some_variable_3, some_variable_4, \
    some_variable_5 = sort_of_long_function_name(parameter_1, parameter_2,
    parameter_3, parameter_4)
```

Edit: Thanks all for the answers. I can't upvote because I'm a noob heh(no rep), so I just wanted to say that I appreciate it. I've read the style guide before and typically I do avoid long lines like this. In this case, I feel I need this function to calculate and return multiple stats. I think I will make some of my naming a bit more concise and look into returning an object or named tuple. Thanks!

Comment: You normally try *not* to create such long lines in the first place. If your variable names in a targeted assignment need more than 79 characters just to get them all lined up, you should refactor your code.

Comment: See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length

Comment: Return a named tuple, for example, and refer to the attributes of that named tuple rather than create 5 variables.

Comment: So, the problem I have here is that I have a function that runs through of a bunch of data and calculates various stats. I don't want to repeat that process every time for each stat individually, as that would be far slower. I think I could shorten some of the variable names at least though.

Comment: Deal with lists and use packing/unpacking?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: isn't that what they are already doing; the function returns a tuple and they are unpacking it. :-)

Comment: You're right, that wasn't very clear, I meant like `after_list = some_func(*before_list)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to *avoid* getting into that situation. If you have a tuple assignment for that many names and you cannot even fit that on a line in 80 characters, it is time for a refactor.

For example, you could have your function return a [`namedtuple` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) instead:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Result = namedtuple('Result', 'foo bar spam ham eggs')

def sort_of_long_function_name(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4):
    return Result(foo_result, bar_result, spam_result, ham_result, eggs_result)

result = sort_of_long_function_name(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5)
do_something_with(result.foo)
do_something_else_with(result.bar)
# etc.
```

Now instead of 5 variables, you have one with helpful named attributes.

This is what the parsing functions in the [`urlparse` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) do, with the `namedtuple` classes even having some additional methods to re-create the parsed URL.

Comment: I don't think this solution generalizes. There are certainly cases where functions return data for which a `namedtuple` would be inappropriate.

Comment: @CeasarBautista: the advice so *avoid* the situation is general. I gave one solution that shows you can avoid the situation.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, this is a weird situation. Backslashes are discouraged because [they can cause subtle bugs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#using-backslash-to-continue-statements) and parentheses are encouraged in their place.

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied
> line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines
> can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in
> parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash
> for line continuation.
>
> -- PEP 8, https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length

So I'd suggest:

```
(long_name_1,
 long_name_2) = 1, 2
```

Comment: This is good to know, thanks. I've been using backslashes in a pinch, but I hate them.

Answer (score 1):

Some general ideas:

- Use shorted names (but readability **is** important).
- Use tuple*, eg. `variables = get_variables()` and refer to them as `variables[n]`. (* or `dict` or `list`).
- It *may* be usefull to encapsulate the variables into class (altrough classes may not be good solution to your problem, it really depends on your code).
- This *may* indicate some larger problem with your code/design.

For guidelines on formatting see [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).